# Matlab - regionprops triangularity and ellipticity

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In Matlab regionprops there is an option to get object Circularity property. Can someone please provide me the equation how to calculate object triangularity? Is ellipticity equal to MajorAxisLength/MinorAxisLength?

Comment: For "ellipticity", you're probably looking for `'Eccentricity'`. I have no idea what triangularity might be.

Comment: Eccentricity is the ratio of the distance between the foci of the ellipse and its major axis length

Answer (score 1):

“ellipticity” is not one of the features of `regionprops`, I’m not sure where you got that name from. However, if you want to know how much a shape resembles an ellipse, you could compute the ellipse variance. This is the coefficient of variation for the distance of each boundary pixel to the best fit ellipse. (See for example [here](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/structdip_1_1Polygon.html#a39bc9ec53063bbd7b4d78c3518c0ab45).)

Triangularity can be determined using one of Podczeck’s shape features — compare the height times the width to twice the area: 2 *a* / *w h*.
(See for example [here](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/features.html#shape_features_PodczeckShapes).)